# Phone Compatibility

Tags: android, scrollview, compatibility

I have a dialog box which displays a text and image while loading,the text is in html format and the layout automatically scroll when the text is too long.
My text does not scroll in vivo v5,i cannot figure out the problem? Is this a hardware problem or OS problem.Its Version is 5.1

Comment: probably vivo has some kind of modified firmware, which can include any modifications. Put the TextView in a ScrollView to make sure it scrolls

Comment: Please show your code and tell us what you tried, it's hard to help you without code.